# File to JTable, JTable to file

Tags: java, database, swing, file-io, jtable

I have been working on `JTable`,
My project:

1. read data from `database` (I finished this task and able to display in JTable).
2. then display and save data into subgroups into `file` (text/excel).

I have basic knowledge on `JTable` and using the some example code, I could manage to finish my first task. Then struck on second task.

for example

> name| email|
>
> name1|email@email.com
>
> name2|email2@email.com

(I finished this task and able to display in `JTable`)

Then
when user clicks any row
then displayed new table

name|Email

display----

then user should able to save the group with `groupname`

Can anyone has idea about how to update the table dynamically and any suggestions?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Hello Guilaume Polet, I am looking for a way to store the data with a group name in a excel file, then when user selects that group name display the data in the table. Data is in 3 columns name,email,dept and different employee belongs to different groups.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone has idea about how to update the table dynamically and any
>   suggestions?

If you are using `DefaultTableModel` then you have methods like `addRow(..)` which will append a row in the `JTable`. Updating the existing rows in `JTable` is done using `setValueAt(..)` method. No need to call `fireXXXMethod` for `DefaultTableModel`.

Or

If your are using `AbstractTableModel` then use the `setValueAt(..)` method and call `fireXXXMethod` in the table model to refresh the table data.